# MySQL: Delete PARENTS when CHILDREN row deleted

Tags: mysql, cascade

Let's say I have a parent table: `FAMILY_MEMBER`, each having a `unique ID` id.

I also have a `FAMILY` table with `mother_id`, `father_id` and `daughter_id`, each pointing to a `FAMILY_MEMBER` row.

When I delete the `FAMILY` row, I'd like the DB to automatically delete the 3 `FAMILY_MEMBER` parent rows.  This seems to be the exact opposite of what `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` clauses are intended to do.

Comment: A trigger might help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
create trigger t1
    after delete on FAMILY
        for each row
            BEGIN
            delete from family_member
                where id = old.mother_id;
            delete from family_member
                where id = old.fa=ther_id;
            delete from family_member
                where id = old.daughter_id;
            END
```

Or this one (You may use delimiter for the name of trigger and table):

```
create trigger `t1`
    after delete on `FAMILY`
        for each row
            BEGIN
            delete from family_member
                where id = old.mother_id;
            delete from family_member
                where id = old.fa=ther_id;
            delete from family_member
                where id = old.daughter_id;
            END
```